# Check how many downloads a CRAN package has?

Tags: r, cran

How can I get simple download metrics for an R package on CRAN?

I recently released my own package on CRAN and I want to monitor it a bit.

Comment: Have a look here: http://www.nicebread.de/finally-tracking-cran-packages-downloads/

Comment: @989 Thanks.  I saw that post but it seems like excessive work just to get package download counts.  That's why I ended up here.

Comment: [Here](http://www.datasciencemeta.com/rpackages)'s a full list of CRAN packages and the number of downloads

Comment: https://hadley.shinyapps.io/cran-downloads/

Answer (score 52, accepted):

http://cranlogs.r-pkg.org offers a variety of ways to access counts of the number of times a package has been *downloaded* (not installed) from the RStudio CRAN mirror (only), including an API for generating badges automatically and an R package.

For the [mltools package](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=mltools):

Downloads in last month (https://cranlogs.r-pkg.org/badges/last-month/mltools)

[image]

Downloads in last week (https://cranlogs.r-pkg.org/badges/last-week/mltools)

[image]

Downloads in last day (https://cranlogs.r-pkg.org/badges/last-day/mltools)

[image]

Grand total (https://cranlogs.r-pkg.org/badges/grand-total/mltools)

[image]

Answer (score 13):

To get metrics of the number of package downloads (not installations) you could also use the following packages:

- [dlstats](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dlstats/index.html)
- [cranlogs](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/cranlogs/index.html) and
- [adjustedcranlogs](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/adjustedcranlogs/index.html)

Answer (score 10):

You can check the number of downloads a CRAN package has here:

http://www.datasciencemeta.com/rpackages

[image]