# Can we know the country (or area) from where downloads of a CRAN package occur?

Tags: download, package, ip, cran

I've seen several ways to get the number of downloads for a CRAN package: [Check how many downloads a CRAN package has?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40835078/check-how-many-downloads-a-cran-package-has)

Please, is there a way to get where the downloads occur from?

I have searched but have not found any means that allows me to obtain the number of downloads of the indicated package according to the origin of the IP.